# Visual Studio C++ & Boost Lib: cannot find function definition only when BOOST_FOREACH is present

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I've recently installed Visual Studio and started working a bit with the SFML library and Boost library, but I stumbled upon this strange (for me) error, when I'm declaring a static void function in the header file of a static class, Visual Studio tells me "Function definition for 'findTextures' is not found" if and only if the BOOST_FOREACH code is present in the funcion. Any of you know why this happens? Thanks a bunch.

This would be the TextureLoader.h:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class TextureLoader {
public:
    static const sf::Texture& getTexture(sf::String l_name);
    static void findTextures();

private:
    static std::map<sf::String, sf::Texture> textures;
};
```

And this is the TextureLoader.cpp class:

```
#include "TextureLoader.h"

// Get texture using name
const sf::Texture& TextureLoader::getTexture(sf::String l_name) {
    return textures.at(l_name);
}

void TextureLoader::findTextures() {
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    fs::path targetDir("/Textures");
    fs::directory_iterator it(targetDir), eod;
    BOOST_FOREACH(fs::path const &p, std::make_pair(it, eod)) {
        if(fs::is_regular_file(p)) {
            std::cout << p.filename();
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MasterTest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>TextureLoader.cpp
1>Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
1>TextureLoader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::map<class sf::String,class sf::Texture,struct std::less<class sf::String>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class sf::String const ,class sf::Texture> > > TextureLoader::textures" (?textures@TextureLoader@@0V?$map@VString@sf@@VTexture@2@U?$less@VString@sf@@@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBVString@sf@@VTexture@2@@std@@@5@@std@@A)
1>F:\Coding\VSProjects\MasterTest\Debug\MasterTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "MasterTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[The error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbLQM.png)

Comment: Without *exact* and *complete* output from Visual Studio we can't really help. Quoting the error messages (from the *output* window, *not* the errors one!) is essential for anybody to be able to help you.

Comment: @JanHudec just edited the question and added the error log :)

Comment: As **TEXT** from the **OUTPUT** window, please.

Comment: Note that the errors window does also allow textual copy&paste, but I said from the start that you should take it from the output window, not the errors one.

Comment: @JanHudec added output as text, sorry :S

Comment: "Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results". I suspect you are using VS2017 version 15.5, which is not currently supported by boost.

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version, and your Boost version?

Comment: @JanHudec The boost version is 1.65.1 and the VS version is 15.5.1

Comment: @Mankarse, turns out that while it is “not supported”, it should still compile as the message is just a message, not an error. And it does; the problem turned out to be something else, easily identifiable upon *careful* reading of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, read the name of the missing symbol carefully. It says:

```
std::map</*…*/> TextureLoader::textures
```

That's not any function. It is the static member variable. And, well, you are indeed missing that. Your `.cpp` file shall include it's definition, which shall look like:

```
std::map<sf::String, sf::Texture> TextureLoader::textures;
```

Because declaring static member variables is *not* sufficient. You have to define them as well.

Comment: Note: here you also see why the exact output is so important. The original text of the question just said “Function definition for 'findTextures'”, but it turned out to be a completely different symbol that is the problem.

Comment: Ok that seems to do the job although the "Funcion definition for 'findTextures' not found" message is still show with a green underline. Thanks!

Comment: @Crack498, the in-editor error highlight is extremely useful, but it can't be trusted at all times. That's why it's important to check the actual compiler output. For which the error window is usually sufficient, but sometimes there is additional information that is only available in the output window (especially when templates are involved).